# local diffeomorphism.

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential

Let $x: U \subset R^2 \to S$ be the parametrization of a surface of revolution S:
$$x(u,v)=(f(v)cos(u),f(v)sin(u),g(v)), f(v)>0$$
$$U=\{(u,v) \in R^2; 0<u<2\pi,a<v<b\}$$

a) Show that the map $\phi: U \to R^2$ given by
$$\varphi (u,v)=(u,\int \frac{\sqrt{(f'(v))^2+(g'(v))^2}}{f(v)}dv)$$
is a local diffeomorphism.

b) Use part a to prove that a surface of revolution S is locally conformal
to a plane in such a way that each local conformal map $\theta:V \subset S → R^2$ takes the parallels and the meridians of the neighborhood
V into an orthogonal system of straight lines in $\theta (V) \subset R^2$.

honestly i don't have any idea to proceed. For a) i think that continuity is straightforward, because partial derivatives are continuous, so this is derivable and then continuous. What about inverse? the first component is u=u that is derivable but i don´t know how to work with the second component. For b) any idea is welcome.

Comment: Maybe try the Inverse Function Theorem? See Theorem A.1 here: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781118165980.app1#:~:text=1.,R*%20be%20a%20smooth%20function.

Comment: For b what Idea works?